# Передача параметров в класс создания кнопки QPushButton

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, классы, qpushbutton

У меня есть класс с функцией создания кнопки. Мне нужно передать в эту функцию название объекта для другой функции:

`(self.name = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.text, self.parent))`

Обычно она выглядит вот так:

`(FuncBatton0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Exit", window))`

Как мне подставить название, текст и родителя в эту строку, чтобы *Python* не ругался и выполнил код. C *ООП* я сталкиваюсь первый раз.

```
class BattonGenerate():

    def __init__(self, name, text, parent, x, y, nameObj, style, Cursor, sizeX, sizeY):
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
        self.parent = parent
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.nameObj = nameObj
        self.style = style
        self.Cursor = Cursor
        self.sizeX = sizeX
        self.sizeY = sizeY
   
    def Generate (self):
        self.name = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.text, self.parent)
        #self.name.resize(self.sizeX, self.sizeY)
        #self.name.setObjectName(self.nameObj)
        #self.name.setStyleSheet(self.style)
        #self.name.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.format(self.Cursor))
        #self.name.move(self.x, self.y)
        
buttons = BattonGenerate("FuncBatton6", "self", "window", 300, 300, "FuncBatton", "StyleSheet","PointingHandCursor", 76, 76)

buttons.Generate()#"FuncBatton6", "self", "window"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, то что вы привели в качестве примера, понять трудно.

Класс создания кнопки может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize   

# Класс для генерации новых кнопок
class PushButton(QPushButton):  
    def __init__(self, text):       # text, принимаем название для кнопки
        super().__init__()

        self.setText(text)          # текст, отображаемый на кнопке


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        # Создать виджет для содержимого окна
        centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        self.lay = QVBoxLayout(centralwidget)

        self.numButton = 1
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(300, 200))    

        pybutton = QPushButton('Create a button', self)
        self.lay.addWidget(pybutton)
        self.lay.addStretch(1)

        # нажимая кнопку 'Create a button' вызываем слот `clickMethod`
        pybutton.clicked.connect(self.clickMethod)


    def clickMethod(self):
        # создаем экземпляр новой кнопки
        self.newBtn = PushButton('New Button {}'.format(self.numButton)) 

        self.numButton += 1

        # Подключаем вновь созданную кнопку, сигналом(clicked) к слоту(clickNewButton), 
        # слот будет вызываться с параметром `text`
        self.newBtn.clicked.connect(lambda btn, text=self.newBtn.text(): self.clickNewButton(text))

        # Добавляем новую кнопку в Layout
        self.lay.addWidget(self.newBtn) 

    # Слот, будет вызываться по нажатию вновь созданной кнопки
    def clickNewButton(self, text):
        print(text)    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что происходит. Добавьте комментариев в код.

Comment: @ДаниилРассадкин  добавил